# Calling an Activity from Non-Activity class

Tags: android, adapter, synchronization

I've run into this problem where I'm running a background process from a non-activity class.  I have an activity in the foreground.  I wanted to refresh the activity, i.e., call MainActivity.java such that it opens up and doesn't duplicate the application running (Which were causing errors).

To be even more specific, I'm running the android SyncAdapter.java in the background.  My menu refresh item is clicked by the user.  The animation is started to get it spinning in a circle.  Then the call to the sync adapter is made and the background process starts running...  When it completes I make this call back to open a new activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.MainActivity");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
// mContext is a global variable of passed application context.
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

This allowed me to close all open activities/tasks and open up this  new activity for the user to resume at the home page of the application without extra duplicate windows.

The only thing I'm concerned with are those " | " in the code.  Can someone explain to me exactly what is happening in the `intent.setFlags(***)` call?  Are the flags being called one after the other?  Or is the result of each flag being piped to the next flag call?  (Is the " | " considered a pipe call?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a bitwise inclusive OR.

It makes an OR operation at bit level using all the flags, and then invokes the `setFlags` method with the result.

Answer (score 1):

The `|` is a bitwise OR condition. It performs a boolean OR operation at bit level (as opposed to a logical OR with `||`) using the binary values of those flags.

Comment: I marked @Juanjo Vegas answer as the correct one as it came first, but thank you for the extra clarification!